# GLMM estimation of unconditioned means

Tags: mixed-model, glmm, poisson-regression, lsmeans

I'm trying to get estimates of overall means, not conditioned on a factor, from my data in a multilevel model with negative binomial or Poisson distribution. In other words, taking into account my random variables, what is the best estimate of the average of my response variable overall, without factors. As I understand it, I can just use ~1 as my factor, but this does not perfectly match my pooled averages from estimated marginal means using Emmeans. I'm just looking for a sanity check.